# ARM based box running Kernel 4.x. Create and run one GUI application without XServer or least amount of XServer

Tags: linux, gui

I have an ARM based box running mainline kernel 4.x. This box is purpose built for ONE application alone. The backend is working well, now I need to create the front end for that application and it needs to be Graphical. Mouse pointer NOT needed.

To simplify the requirements - I need one fullscreen background image and three small images on top of it side by side. By the use of "arrow" keys I want to move between the three images (options) and hitting "Enter" is to take me to the appropriate next screen.

This front end is to run perpetually and does not need "close" or "minimize" buttons like there are on windows.

I've used "fbi" to show images but it can do only one image at a time and I cannot put another image on top of it. I briefly tried Python (not my strength) but it seems that ptinker relies on X. I'm not sure if it can do what I require.

I'm lost on which language/library to use to get this application started. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: What about ncurses?

Comment: Directfb. Direct Frame Buffer

Comment: qt on LinuxFB too

Comment: Thanks jc__. I was pretty sure I responded earlier but can't find that comment. Anyhow, I went with QT. It works quite well for my needs.